# IDE and tooling issues developing for windows from linux

Tags: linux, windows, go, ide

I am trying to develop a simple windows GUI in go (first attempt).

After considering a few packages to get me started, I landed on this https://github.com/lxn/walk and it seemed ideal. I cross-compiled from my ubuntu laptop and the provided demo worked on all target platforms (win7/8/10)

The problems came when I tried to start developing from my linux laptop - initially in atom, but I've since tried with sublime, emacs and phpstorm and noticed an issue with go get (so I'm guessing it's the underlying go tooling that's failing)

The first error I'm seeing is:

> /../github.com/lxn/walk/tooltiperrorpresenter.go:8: undefined: ToolTip

This affects development across all affected IDEs tested:

- disables autocomplete
- halts linting
- cant test
- gofmt worked in some (perhaps tool ordering)
  affecting any file referencing this lib.

And this is the first of many errors which seem to be due to the library importing its internal `win` package which contains files which are marked with the flag:

```
// +build windows
```

I cunningly decided to start ripping out these tags from the lib - hoping that would at least allow me to get on with development, but then I started seeing new errors regarding too many arguments being passed to syscalls in the win package - presumably because the different platforms (win/nix) have different numbers of parameters in those syscalls.

I then tried marking **everything** with the `//+build windows` flag, but the parade of errors remained unchanged.

I found some issues on the project github which are related:
https://github.com/lxn/win/issues/26 : `no buildable Go source files`
and there are solutions for "go getting" the files but none so far for my IDE woes.

I've also seen this type of issue in some other windows specific go libraries so I don't think it's an issue for the package author. But I would be interested to hear any solutions from a code architecture perspective if they exist

I haven't actually tried doing this from a windows VM yet (I presume that would solve the issue from my end) - but its a bit of a jarring solution as I'm already juggling vms to test the app so I'm keen to find another way.

**TLDR:**

> Do I have to work from Windows machine / vm in order to have a fully
>   functional IDE when developing for windows from linux or is there a way to satisfy the go tooling

Comment: You may need a space after the command line for build: `// +build`. Otherwise you may consider using filenames to limit build which more IDEs might respect. See https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Go_Path

Comment: I'm pretty sure that missing space is just a typo in the question but for good measure I'll have another go at marking everything with with windows build flag again and report back. Im not sure I understand the suggestion on filenames, would be helpul if you could eleborate

Comment: Please see the link I put: If a file's name, after stripping the extension and a possible _test suffix, matches any of the following patterns:

    *_GOOS
    *_GOARCH
    *_GOOS_GOARCH